# How does FLANN select what algorithm and parameters to use?

Tags: nearest-neighbor, flann, approximate-nn-searching

FLANN (Fast Library for Approximate Nearest Neighbors) is a library for performing fast approximate nearest neighbor searches in high dimensional spaces. It contains a collection of algorithms we found to work best for nearest neighbor search and a system for automatically choosing the best algorithm and optimum parameters depending on the dataset. FLANN is written in C++ and contains bindings for the following languages: C, MATLAB, Python, and Ruby. https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann

What are the algorithms available to FLANN and how does it choose which algorithm and parameters to use?

I ask because, I noticed a x10 speed decrease using a voxel filter prior to using FLANN and wish to figure out what to attribute it to. The voxel filter removes 70% of the points in the data, but the speed decrease seems to much greater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FLANN uses these algorithms ([defines.h](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/blob/1d04523268c388dabf1c0865d69e1b638c8c7d9d/src/cpp/flann/defines.h#L79)):

```
FLANN_INDEX_LINEAR
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE          
FLANN_INDEX_KMEANS 
FLANN_INDEX_COMPOSITE 
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE_SINGLE
FLANN_INDEX_HIERARCHICAL
FLANN_INDEX_LSH
```

Section 2, last paragraph, from [FAST APPROXIMATE NEAREST NEIGHBORS
WITH AUTOMATIC ALGORITHM CONFIGURATION, Mins, Lowe, 2009](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Elowe/papers/09muja.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj3uYvFyMHsAhWoUhUIHTu2B4MQFjABegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3phAP6YC0lJOeAeKtSryoG), it mentions:

> In our experiments, one of two algorithms obtained the best performance, depending on the dataset and desired precision. These algorithms used either the **hierarchical
> k-means tree** or **multiple randomized kd-trees**.

Section 3.3 answers your question about how FLANN chooses the algorithm it appears (from the sample) to be the best at hand. Here is half of it:

[image]